# Android listview being updated by mutliple threads.You see an issue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Maybe related to previous questions I posted but this is a different flavor. I have a list view with customized base adapted that takes Vector (it used to take ArrayList but I made it Vector as I heard it is threadsafer). The problem that I have two threads updating this vector and as a result the listview updating the GUI on data set change. How can I ensure no threading issue happen? Is what  I did sufficient?

Part of the Base adapter class:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private Vector<Room> roomList;
    private Context context;


    RoomListAdapter(Context c){
        this.context = c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { 
        return roomList.size();
    }

    public void setData(Vector<Room> roomData){
        roomList= roomData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
        @Override
    public Object getItem(int number) {
        return roomList.get(number);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           // Here I get the Room based on position and update my view
       }
}
```

My class that updates the list concurrently has the following method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    roomVect = new Vector<RoomDataExtra>();
    mylistAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
   }
private synchronized void addRoom(Room roomData){
    roomVect.add(roomData);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myListAdapter.setData(roomVect);
            listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
        }
    });
     }
```

and offcourse the addRoom is being called by my threads many times. So there is a good chance that my thead calls this while the list is update. Note that it is the same vector being passed to the list which is updating from it

Do you see an issue with above ? How do you recommend solving if there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector is really no safer than anything else here.  You need to totally block off all concurrent access with a semaphore.  That means when something wants to change your list, you need to take a semaphore first and wait for the other thread to be finished (and give up the semaphore when done).  You also need to do that on the UI side where you're reading the list-  but you have to do take it before reading any of the list, and release it when done reading the entire list.

A less complex way would be to serialize all the list changes to the UI thread.  When the thread that wants to change the list needs to change it, have it post a Runnable to a Handler on the main thread.  The Runnable would do the actual changing.  This way all of the actual reads and writes will happen on one thread.  This will at least avoid concurrency exceptions, although it won't prevent problems if multiple indices need to change visually at the same exact time.

If that needs to happen (synchronized changes to the visuals of multiple items), the best way to do it is to have the update thread update a deep copy of the list.  Then when its done, change the copy that the UI is looking at to this new array, and create a new deep copy for the update thread.

TLDR:  Multithreading is hard.  Based on the fact you think vector is really safer, you don't seem to know much about concurrency issues.  You really need to study before attempting to use threads.